# Why can't I create uicontrol object in Octave while I can in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, octave, matlab-figure

I am using Octave 4.0.3 and qt graphics toolkit. I am trying to make a panel with button on it using following code:

```
clear all
close all
h = figure;
hp = uipanel('Title','Main Panel','FontSize',12,...
             'BackgroundColor','red',...
             'Position',[.25 .1 .67 .67]);
b=uicontrol('Parent',hp,'Visible','on');
```

It works in MATLAB but not in Octave.

Comment: In your first script you only make a figure visible, which is probably its default value.  then the second code clears all. Is this really your code?

Comment: The second code is new script. It is one of the examples I found for gui beginners and uicontrol is not working for me but uipanel does.

Comment: But didnt you say you wanted a `uicontrol`? Have you tried writing code that has the function `uicontrol`?

Comment: Yes, I did. The first script should open new figure with pushbutton. But it is not showing.

Comment: Combine the two... you need a uipanel to put a uicontrol on

Comment: I just tried that but the button is not showing. 
f=figure;
set (f, 'Name', 'GUI Example') 
set (f, 'Color', 'red') 
p = uipanel ("title", "Panel Title", "position", [.25 .25 .5 .5]);
b1 = uicontrol ("parent", p, "string", "A Button", "position",[.3 .25 .11 .2]);

Comment: please, read [ask], edit your question to add a real proper example, none of your tests attempts to create a button

Comment: Thank you I am going to read that.. That was my first question ever. :D

Comment: @Ivana I'm getting `error: __gnuplot_draw_figure__: unknown object class, uipanel`. Is that what you're seeing?

Comment: Are you using MacPorts? See https://trac.macports.org/ticket/51690

Comment: I just tried it in 4.0.3 (on Windows) and it worked fine.

Comment: I am not getting any type of error. Yes, I am using MAC. That must be it.

Comment: @beaker: You have to use the qt toolkit to use uicontrols. FLTK or gnuplot (as your error message shows) won't work

Comment: @Andy ooh cool, thanks :D

Comment: and for the record, I've put an example to show whats's possible to https://github.com/octave-de/macgyver_utils/blob/master/demo_uicontrol.m

Comment: Also, are you using the Octave graphical interface? Or the pure command-line one? I think the command-line one defaults to gnuplot or something, whereas the graphical one will use Qt by default (unless you change it explicitly with the `graphics_toolkit` command). So if you're using the commandline interface, try the same example in the graphical interface.    (Also, it's worth upgrading to 4.2 if you can)